# .dt accessor fails, but python functions work

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

For some reason the .dt accessor is having funny results compared to regular datetime functions in pandas.  This screen shot is the best example:

[image]

As you can see at exactly one date all dates start failing, however vanilla python will work just fine:

[image]

Here's the code I'm trying.

```
import pandas as pd

## Add Year Index and Month Index
# df_final['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('Y')
# df_final['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')
# df_final['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
fn = lambda x: x.month

r = df_final['Date'].apply(fn)
```

Data set is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DdpTu9VqaZzRBwb51zp51FY9FpKf9DUq/view?usp=sharing)

How is this happening?  Its double weird because those DateTime values are created at the same time and inserted into both rows as a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected:

```
df_final = pd.read_csv('ToolsForPython.csv', parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=False)
df_final['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('Y')
df_final['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')
df_final['MonthNum'] = df['Date'].dt.month  # rename columns to avoid override
```

Output:

```
>>> df_final
           Name       Date         Account  Debit  Credit  Balance  IsShowing  Year    Month  MonthNum
0    WES ARMIJO 2021-11-08   ACCRUED ASSET    NaN   550.0    550.0          1  2021  2021-11        11
1    WES ARMIJO 2021-11-11   ACCRUED ASSET    NaN    50.0    600.0          1  2021  2021-11        11
2    WES ARMIJO 2021-11-24   ACCRUED ASSET    NaN    50.0    650.0          1  2021  2021-11        11
3    WES ARMIJO 2021-12-01  DRAW ON TOOLS   514.0     NaN    136.0          1  2021  2021-12        12
4    WES ARMIJO 2021-12-04   ACCRUED ASSET    NaN    50.0    186.0          1  2021  2021-12        12
..          ...        ...             ...    ...     ...      ...        ...   ...      ...       ...
234  PAUL JONES 2022-07-21   ACCRUED ASSET    NaN    50.0   5907.8          1  2022  2022-07         7
235  PAUL JONES 2022-08-04   ACCRUED ASSET    NaN    50.0   5957.8          1  2022  2022-08         8
236  PAUL JONES 2022-08-18   ACCRUED ASSET    NaN    50.0   6007.8          1  2022  2022-08         8
237  PAUL JONES 2022-09-01   ACCRUED ASSET    NaN    50.0   6057.8          1  2022  2022-09         9
238  PAUL JONES 2022-09-15   ACCRUED ASSET    NaN    50.0   6107.8          1  2022  2022-09         9

[239 rows x 10 columns]

>>> df_final.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 239 entries, 0 to 238
Data columns (total 10 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------     --------------  -----         
 0   Name       239 non-null    object        
 1   Date       239 non-null    datetime64[ns]  # HERE
 2   Account    239 non-null    object        
 3   Debit      26 non-null     float64       
 4   Credit     213 non-null    float64       
 5   Balance    239 non-null    float64       
 6   IsShowing  239 non-null    int64         
 7   Year       239 non-null    period[A-DEC]   # HERE
 8   Month      239 non-null    period[M]       # HERE
 9   MonthNum   239 non-null    int64           # HERE
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3), int64(2), object(2), period[A-DEC](1), period[M](1)
memory usage: 18.8+ KB
```